# How do I punch faster?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I used to play Skyrim with Dual Flurry Mod, Dual Parrying Mod, and Fist Grandmaster Mod which allowed far better and practical unarmed combat. One problem that I encountered was the fast unarmed combat would only work if you played in third person. I think the Joy of Perspective Mod could fix this issue, however I did test it yet.

I never played the Skyrim Requiem Mod, but it looks cool and hardcore, but it modifies all of the skill trees, which makes Fist Grand-master mod incompatible.

Is there away to improve/speedup the unarmed combat in Skyrim Requiem mod or is not worth pursuing? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one thing I know how to improve your speed and that is to wear a full light armor set. If you wear a Light Armor set you can have these advantages according to [this wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Light_Armor):

- **Lighter and less movement penalty.**
- Less noisy, making sneaking easier.
- Unhindered perk (worn light armor is weightless) is available 20
  levels earlier than Heavy Armor's Conditioning, and doesn't require
  taking two highly situational perks to unlock.
- Uses less stamina when sprinting.
- Stamina recovers faster with Wind Walker perk.
- **Can be faster than the enemy, allowing you to run away from a battle
  or pursue a fleeing enemy.**
- The lighter weight allows for the carrying of multiple suits of
  armor, each fine-tuned for specific enemies and situations, without
  drastically taking up encumbrance.
- Fully mastering the Light Armor tree requires two fewer perks over
  Heavy Armor (10 total points versus 12), allowing for more growth in
  other skill trees.
- Deft Movement has a small chance to negate combat damage, increasing
  overall defense.